# C++ Error with code

Tags: c++, arguments

I am currently studying C++ and have a program with this code that is working fine. I copied this code from my first program into my second but I cannot figure out what is causing the error. The error is "Error: argument type of `StudentResults` is not compatible with parameter type of `StudentResults`

The code is as follows, I know some of it is quoted out this is just to stop some things from working until I get this error sorted. This is only a sample of the code that I think the error lies in, if more code is needed I will add the rest. The error is where the **  ** are, these are not actually in the code just to highlight where the error is. Thanks

```
//Prototypes - common
void press_key(HANDLE hdl, int col, int row);
void message(HANDLE hdl,  char mess[], int col, int row);
char again(HANDLE hdl, int col, int row);
void set_menu(HANDLE hdl );
int  get_option(HANDLE hdl, int c , int r , int min , int max);
void gotoXY( HANDLE hdl, SHORT x, SHORT y );
void clrScr(HANDLE hdl );
void getscreen(HANDLE hdl, char name[]);
void validateString(HANDLE hdl, int col, int row, int min, int max,char str[], char errMessage[]);
int validateNumber(HANDLE hdl, int col, int row, int min, int max, char errMessage[]);

//prototypes - menu
int  populateStock( struct   StudentDetails   student_details[]);
void reportResults(HANDLE hdl, struct StudentDetails student_details[], int size);
void displayBySurname(HANDLE hdl,struct StudentDetails student_details[], int  size);
void displayByStudentNumber(HANDLE hdl, struct StudentDetails student_details[30], int size);
void updateStock(HANDLE hdl, struct StudentDetails student_details[], int size );
void addStock(HANDLE hdl,  struct StudentDetails student_details[], int & size);

struct StudentResults
{
int candidateNo;
char forename[20], surname[20];
int section[5];
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
// insert HANDLE hdl
HANDLE hdl = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

    //Data Declaration
    int option, size;
    struct StudentResults student_details[30] ;

    // fill array with some stock details
    size = populateStock(student_details);   // error here

    do
    {
        set_menu(hdl);
        option=get_option(hdl, 44,20,1,7);      
        switch(option)
        {
             case 1:;  //reportStock(hdl, student_details, size);
             case 2:;  //displayStockByCat(hdl, student_details, size); 
             case 3:;  //searchStock(hdl, stock_details, size);
             case 4:;  //searchStockByDesc(hdl, stock_details, size);
             case 5:;  //updateStock(hdl, stock_details,size);
             case 6:; //addStock(hdl, stock_details,size);
        }
    } while (option !=7);

    return 0;
}
int populateStock( struct StudentResults student_details[])
{
    int size;

    student_details[0].candidateNo  =  1004;    
    strcpy_s(student_details[0].forename , "Joe");          
    strcpy_s(student_details[0].surname , "Bloggs"); 
    student_details[0].section[0] = 20.87;
    student_details[0].section[1] = 20.87;
    student_details[0].section[2] = 20.87;
    student_details[0].section[3] = 20.87;
    student_details[0].section[4] = 20.87;


return 1;
}
```

Comment: Where is populateStock declared?

Comment: You want to remove the ** from the code too, and highlight the error with a comment! ** is very misleading for C/C++ programs

Comment: The weird thing is that you comment out the real code, but put the commenting `** **` in plain code. Just saying... It is better to signal the error with a comment. For example `// <----- ERROR here!!!`

Comment: New to the forum, just thought it would highlight the comment simply. I have it changed now. I will add the code for the populate stock if you wish.

Comment: Post your code of populateStock function

Comment: Added all declarations for functions and added the populateStock function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means, what are passing as parameter of `populateStock` is not the type of parameter it takes. It takes different type of parameter. As you didn't post the code of function `populateStock` I can't point you precisely but this is the best I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated, found the fault.

Answer (score 0):

From your function `populateStock` definition:

```
int  populateStock( struct   StudentDetails   student_details[]);
```

`populateStock` is accepting `struct StudentDetails` as type of argument but your passing to it an object of type `struct StudentResults` which is an incompatible type.

```
struct StudentResults student_details[30] ;

// fill array with some stock details

/*This will generate an error as your passing an incompatible type */
size = populateStock(student_details);
```